# google optimize redirect test shows different amount of traffic even the variant is divided 50%-50%

Tags: google-analytics, ab-testing, google-optimize

We have a Google Optimize redirect test currently set in 50-50 traffic allocation.

[Here's the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t2Ms.jpg)

However, when we checked on the results, seems like the traffic allocation is not 50-50. There's a big difference in traffic for each of variant.

[Pageview results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1fER.jpg)

How did this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Is Canine Course your B test? Is it possible a bunch of those people are going directly to that page, therefore bypassing the experiment?

If that isn't it, I would look to things like date range to make sure everyone you are looking at is within the experiment period. Also look at the targeting settings you are using -- if you are not just targeting by url, do some visitors to your 'A' page fall outside of you target? If so you can use segmenting in GA to narrow down to the population you are targeting.